# tcpdump failed withi permission denied on centos when using with rotated file option

Tags: tcpdump

When I use tcpdump on centos 6, I got a permission denied error even when I was root. My command is like this:

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -G 10 -w test.dmp port 80
```

i have tried with -Z root or -Z my_username but no luck

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -Z root -G 10 -w test.dmp port 80
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -Z myuser_name -G 10 -w test.dmp port 80
```

Does anybody know how to make it work?

Comment: Could you please show us the full output?

Comment: the first file is created fine but when it tried to create a second file, it error with this error: tcpdump: test.dmp: Permission denied

Comment: I found a bug report for it http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=1570 but i can't find a solution. I am using centos 6.

Comment: Which `tcpdump` version are you using?

Comment: Could you be starting the second process a little early such that the file is still open in the first tcpdump while trying the second dump.  Maybe a sleep 1 between the two invokations might help.

Answer (score 6):

If you plan to use file rotation, make sure the directory you write into is world writable.

tcpdump drops privileges shortly after opening the first file specified for writing with `-w`, so it will not be able to write to a directory if:

1. it doesn't own or isn't a part of the owning group of the directory or
2. that directory is not world-writable.